# insert many to many

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, backend

У меня есть 3 таблицы: 1 - `movies`, 2- `actors`, 3 - `actor_movie`.
Я пытаюсь при создании нового фильма(через форму) записать в первую таблицу значения(из формы), а потом в 3-ю таблицу записать `id` фильма и `id-шники` актеров, которые в нем снимались (которых я выбрал в форме через `select`).
`id` актеров я получаю с той же формы что значения для таблицы `movies(1)`;

Вопрос: как мне правильно написать `INSERT` запрос в БД ? 
Я предполагаю что нужно использовать цикл...

Comment: Лучше попробовать вставку через `values (...), (...), (...), (...), ` https://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-insert-multiple-records/ . C другой стороны, с подготовленным запросом в PDO если грубо говоря - запрос будет в кэше и поэтому инсерт в цикле тоже возможен

Comment: https://thisinterestsme.com/pdo-prepared-multi-inserts/ - вот так можно за один запрос сделать за счет синтаксиса `values (...), (...), (...), (...),` . Ну и цикла, конечно

Comment: Какая разница, many to many или нет? Обычный запрос, вставка нескольких строк по два цисла в каждой. Вставлять можно как угодно.

Comment: Сергей Мишин, вы говорите сделать как-то так values (...), (...), (...), (...). Но я не знаю сколько актёров выберет пользователь и соответсвенно сколько (...) должно быть ...